Prevent the change to the window title by an application executed from the default Windows command prompt
I have a batch file (mybatfile.bat) containing the following code:
@echo off
python main.py

So I create a shortcut to the mybatfile.bat for removing the "Administrator" string in title after running it.
(after the shortcut file runs, mybatfile.bat executes & the window title becomes "mybatfile")
However after several seconds, when Python runs an application, the title changes to "Administrator mybatfile" (In this case I programmed Python to run chromedriver.exe and when chromedriver.exe runs, it changes the title).
I want to prevent the change of the title after running any application in the command prompt window (I don't want the string "Administrator" to appear in the title) because I want to kill the process by name in the Task Manager.
I must use the default Windows terminal, the simple Windows terminal. Don't ask why. Please just help me stop the title from changing after running applications in the Windows command prompt.

That application  (chromedriver.exe) runs in its own process (it has its own process ID).  It does not run in the same process as the Windows command prompt (cmd.exe).  Windows command prompt is only its grandparent.  Killing the grandparent or parent (Python in this case) does not automatically kill all of its children, so even if you manage to kill cmd.exe or python.exe the application process (chromedriver.exe) will remain running.  Does that matter to you ?
